# Overwritting cell data with existing formula output based on another condition

Tags: excel

I have come across an issue when designing sheet for task completion. I would like to display the word "Completed" in a cell where I already have an existing formula. The existing formula is `=MAX(0,C22-TODAY())` which shows the amount of remaining days left to the specified deadline. I have added additional formula into the same cell to display the word "completed" once the countdown is completed and the deadline is reached. The current formula is `=MAX(0,C22-TODAY())&IF(D22>0,"Completed","")`. However, now I have an issue as the final output looks as `0Completed` where the zero is still displaying along with the word completed. 
How can I get rid off the zero? and leave the word completed only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try nesting the two formulas instead of concatenating them.

```
=IF(D22>0, "Completed", MAX(0,C22-TODAY()))
```

Comment: remember to accept as correct answer ! (For my problem too IF it works this time)